# How to pass a Data Table into a stored procedure in Uipath

Tags: uipath

How to pass a data table into a stored procedure in Uipath.

"
This is how to solve this in Uipath how to solve the SP merge is later.

I can send a hole Table in the Insert activity but i need to check on the otherside with a merge so it dont just input alredy existing data. But cant find a way in  Uipath how to send the DateTable into  a StoredProcedure
"

Comment: into sp in uipath ?

Comment: This is how to solve this in Uipath how to solve the SP is later. But to passs a DataTable into a activity in Uipath. I cant send a hole Table in the Insert activity but i need to check on the otherside with a merge so it dont just input alredy existing data. But cant find a way in  Uipath how to send the values into  a StoredProcedure

Comment: u mean to say passing datatable to the controller then to storeprocedure?

Answer (score -1):

In order to work with a Datatable in a stored procedure, you will most likely have to serialize it first.

> JsonConvert.SerializeObject(DataTable)

This should work if you MUST use a Datatable in a stored procedure, but you should look for an alternate data structure to ease your work.